# Smallest close sphere containing $V$

Tags: vectors, spheres

Suppose I have a finite set of vectors $V = \{v_1, v_2, ..., v_n\} \subset \mathbb{R}^3$. What is the best way to find the smallest close sphere containing $V$?

Comment: Try it with two vectors, then three.  Generalization should be clear.

Comment: Did you understand the hint? Why not using the largest vector as determining the diameter of the sphere?

Comment: @Moti, do you mean the largest vector, or the largest distance among pairs of vectors? I don't think any will work. E.g. think of the four vertices of a regular tetrahedron placed far from the origin of coordinates. The largest vector will be too large, and the largest distance among pairs of vertices would be the side of the tetrahedron, which is too small to be the diameter of the enclosing sphere.

Comment: To the best of my knowledge a vector has direction and size - no location.

Comment: @Moti, as elements of $\mathbb{R}^3$ they are just triples of real numbers, and could be used to represent points in 3-dim space.

Comment: Triplets are actually points unless you refer to the origin as the "start" of the vector. Or I am not following what you mean by triplets.

Comment: @Moti - Note that the problem statement says $V \subset \mathbb{R}^3$, and $\mathbb{R}^3$ consists of all triples of real numbers, i.e., $\mathbb{R}^3 = \{(x_1,x_2,x_3) \mid x_1,x_2,x_3 \in \mathbb{R}\}$. It turns out that $\mathbb{R}^3$ with addition defined $(x_1,x_2,x_3) + (y_1,y_2,y_3) = (x_1+y_1,x_2+y_2,x_3+y_2)$ and scalar multiplication $r (x_1,x_2,x_3) = (rx_1,rx_2r,x_3)$ is also a vector space over $\mathbb{R}$, so it is legitime to call its elements "vectors", but they still are triples of real numbers.The problem could be to find the smallest sphere in $\mathbb{R}^3$ enclosing $V$.